# Azure DevOps Artifacts Feed fills with NuGet Gallery packages

Tags: azure-devops

Currently I try to establish on my Azure DevOps Server (self-hosted) a `nuget/dotnet pack` build- and release pipeline.

- **build pipeline** build the sources, pack them to `nupkg` and upload it to the `drop artifacts`.
- **release pipeline** grep that `nupkg` from the `drop` folder and perform a `nuget push`, when the package get updated.

So I create a **artifacts feed**, test the pipelines, run agents connected to the feed and build solutions, everything was fine. Some hours later, I check my feed and recognize that the feed contains standard packages from the **NuGet Gallery**.

[image]

First I thought, I pushed accidently with my pipelines, so I removed the feed and a bit later (after background cleanup) I create a new one with the same name. Few minutes later, the packages from **NuGet Gallery** were inside again without running my pipelines.

**How is that possible, do I misunderstanding something?**

Config for my self-hosted agents `\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`:

````
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="MyFeed1" value="https://mylocalurl.de/ColA/_packaging/ProjA/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Artifacts Feed fills with NuGet Gallery packages

This is an expected behavior.

That because your private Nuget Feed set `nuget.org` as an **Upstream source by default** if you set Package from public sources enable when you create the this feed:

[image]

Then go to `Setting`->`Upstream source`, you will find there are three public sources listed:

[image]

[image]

You could use the **source** filter to select the source of the package.

When we download any packages from the Upstream sources, Azure Artifacts feed will **cache** these packages automatically when we download any packages from the Upstream sources, so that **we could see it next time and no need to download it from the Upstream sources again**.

If you do not want use cache those packages, you could select the next option `Only use packages published to this feed` when you create the feed.

Comment: Is any disadvantages of setting option use public sources packages ? Or what is the recommended approach enable or disable this?